# Very poor performance on Django template rendering

Tags: django, performance, amazon-web-services, django-templates

I have been suffered with this issue for days. I am running a django application on a AWS EC2 server (8 core CPU), configure with Nginx+uWSGI, uwsgi is using 8 socket files.

I wrote two views, view A returns HttpResponse('ok') and view B loads and returns a template file (no context rendering).

When I performed 50 concurrent requests on the the view A. The view B works just fine, however if I run the load testing against the view B (template rendering), the server becomes extremely slow. Any ideas?

Comment: The Django template engine isn't all that fast, which is a known fact, if you want to speed up template rendering then you should look into using Jinja2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I figured out that's a context processor I added to Django caused this issue.